# Hadoop Java Program always runs in standalone mode

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, classpath

I've written a Java program that uses Hadoop. I execute my program from the command line using "java -jar prog.jar" and I can see that it runs in stand alone mode. I can tell because the JobTracker and TaskTracker daemons don't need to be running for my program to execute successfully. If I execute my program using "hadoop jar prog.jar" (with the map/reduce daemons off), naturally it doesn't work.

I want my java program to execute in pseudo-distributed mode but I've got a feeling that it can't find the config files. I tried executing it as "java -cp /usr/hadoop-1.1.1/conf -jar prog.jar" in order to point it to where the config files are located but still no dice.

I've got a feeling that the classpath is wrong or something. I'm a noob so any help is appreciated. Thanks,

mj

Here's a snippet of my job starting code with the configuration object.

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();     
    Job job = new Job(config);
    job.setJobName("Test");
    job.setJarByClass(MyMapper.class);      

    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(MyInputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://hadoop0.hq.net:54310/" + saFileName));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("hdfs://hadoop0.hq.net:54310/" + saFileName + "-output"));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I execute my program from the command line using "java -jar prog.jar" and I can see that it runs in stand alone mode.

This is not true. The `java -jar` command is used to run standalone java applications. To run a Hadoop job you need use the `hadoop jar` command as you mentioned.

You need setup Hadoop in your environment before you run any tasks. If you are not ready you can follow the steps in [this post](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/hadoop-pseudo-distributed-installation/) or [offical documents](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/single_node_setup.html#PseudoDistributed). 
You can verify the setup by running some of examples provided with Hadoop distribution:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

If the above command runs successfully, you can then try your own tasks.

Edit:
You can use `Runtime.exec` to invoke the `hadoop jar` as follows:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = input.readLine();
while (line != null) {
  // process output of the task
  // ...
}
input.close();
// wait for the task complete
p.waitFor();
int ret = p.exitValue();
// process the task result
// ...
```

Comment: I found if I add the config files manually like config.addResource(new Path("core-site.xml")); then it works fine.

Comment: The `bin/hadoop` script would setup the environment(classpath, config file path, etc) for you. `bin/hadoop jar` invokes `core/org/apache/hadoop/util/RunJar.java`, which invokes your main class. You don't need to add the resource manually if you use `bin/hadoop jar` command and I think it would be a preferred approach.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a Java service that has a web interface via which jobs can be started. When the job is complete, my service sends the results back. bin/hadoop jar didn't seem appropriate  to me for some reason.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a wrapper for `bin/hadoop jar`, hope it helps.